# Recyclerview inside ViewPager which is inside nested Scroll View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling, android-nestedscrollview

I have used the following code inside coordinator layout and i am using custom collapsing toolbar design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backg">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="User Name"
                        android:id="@+id/username"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:id="@+id/business"
                        android:text="Users Business"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:title=""
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:id="@+id/back"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="User Name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp">

             <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now what problem i am facing is, when i run this app on Lower OS versions, it is all okay while scrolling in all viewpager fragments Recyclerviews, but when i use OS above Android.M, recyclerview's height is out of display screen, and it is not visible enough to see the item on screen. Please help me resolve my problem. I have designed my custom collapsing bar layout, but it is all okay with it in lower Android OS.

**[EDITED]**
Here are some snapshots when i add margin_bottom of my actionbar size. 
[image]
<--- Snapshot End.
You can see the viewpagers height is less then screen size as we are using marginBottom.
**Now**
For Higher varients, its all okay as below while using marginBottom.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your reviews and answers to my questions, But after digging much i didnt found anything useful, and though to set height programmatically. so i tried snippet below, and that works like a charm.
well for heigher varients, set marginBottom with actionbar size in your layout xml in NestedScrollView and for lower varients, Use this Hack below.

```
 NestedScrollingView nsv = findViewByID(R.id.nsv);

 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lpm = new android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        lpm.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        lpm.setBehavior(new android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior());
        nsv.setLayoutParams(lpm);
        nsv.requestLayout();
    }
```

Again, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding linearLayout on top of the viewpapger and give a try.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="800dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: I have already used scrollview, and i am using collapsing toolbar, so i used it with nestedscrollviewenabled="true" too, but is doesn't work anymore. the problem i am facing is with height of viewpage held inside NestedScrollView.

Comment: I have tried the suggestion you told me to sir, but the issue i am facing is viewPagers height. it is occupying full height when i add fillViewPort="true" in nested scrolling layout, and due to this, recyclerview is occupying full height of viewpager, and in conclusion, my other items of recyclerview are goung outts screen, but heah, a hack is when i add marginBottom of my toolbar height, it is working properly, but now, the problem is with lower varients

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right you have to add the margin of the toolbar (as you already said). I solved this problem by adding `layout_gravity` as following.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Comment: yes, it is solving a problem for heigher varients, whenever i add margin Bottom of actionbar size.... But this margin is problematic for lower OS varients and shows blank space(of given margin) below viewpager in lower OS.

Comment: You added `android:layout_gravity` as well?

Comment: Your problem could also be that you use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the FrameLayout. I had a lot of trouble using that in the coordinatorlayout.

Comment: It was just a sample, actually i used all different layouts to sort it out, and all other tricks, but none of them worked, the issue i am facing is size of viewpager, it is taking all height of screen.

Comment: Then pls post your final layout so I can take a look at it.